# Construct a circle of a given radius such that a ray of a given angle cuts out a given chord length (see diagram)

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

> Given a segment $r$, a segment $c$, and an angle $\angle AOB$, construct (straightedge and compass) a circle whose center is on ray $OA$, whose radius is congruent to $r$, and where the chord created by ray $OB$ is congruent to $c$.
>
> Source: Based on Kiselev's *Geometry*

[image]

My solution is below.  It seems too complicated than I would expect, so I ask:

1. Is it correct?
2. Is there a simpler solution?

Background: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4840585/construction-given-two-intersecting-lines-find-the-point-where-their-distance) for background. Thank you to X-Rui for helping me out.

---

**Solution:** Let segment $c$ have endpoints $U$ and $V$.  Draw two circles with radius $r$ and centers $U, V$ respectively and label one of their intersections $X$.  Drop the perpendicular from $X$ to $UV$ and label its foot $T$.

[image]

From $O$, erect segment $OC$ perpendicular to $OB$ with length congruent to $TX$.  From $C$, draw ray $CD$ parallel to $OB$ and label its intersection with $OA$ as $D$.

Now draw circle $\bigcirc D$ with radius $r$.  Label the intersections of  $\bigcirc D$ with $OA$ as $F$ and $G$.  Then chord $FG$ is congruent to $UV$, completing the construction.

**Proof:** Drop the perpendicular from $D$ to $OB$ and let its foot be $H$.  Segment $HD \cong OC \cong TX$.  Likewise, $DF \cong DG \cong XU \cong XV$.  Therefore $FG \cong UV$ and $\bigcirc D$ is the desired circle.

Comment: The only simplification is to use for the first phase the line OB.